# PRDownloader Auth Token

Tags: android

I'm using [PRDownloader](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/PRDownloader). I want to download a file from my Google Drive, hence I need to supply `Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>` .. how can I do that with PRDownloader? I don't see any way to do this from the website, but perhaps there's some unofficial way?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else stumbling into this. You can try:

```js
 PRDownloader.download(url, dir.absolutePath, filename)
            .setHeader("accept-language", headers.getString("accept-language"))
            .setHeader("Authorization", headers.getString("Authorization"))
            .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem and ended up using [Fetch](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch) instead. A working example looks then like this. The important line can be found in the download method:

```
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
```

Here is the complete DummyActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var fetch: Fetch

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

        val fetchConfiguration =
            FetchConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .setDownloadConcurrentLimit(10)
                .setProgressReportingInterval(100)
                .setHttpDownloader(OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient))
                .build()

        fetch = getInstance(fetchConfiguration)

        button.setOnClickListener { download() }
    }



    private fun download() {

        val url = "https://yourdomain.com/download/path.zip"
        val dirPath = getExternalFilesDir(null)?.path
        val fileName = "ResultFileName.zip"

        val accessToken = "your_access_token"

        val request = Request(url, Uri.fromFile(File(dirPath, fileName)))
        request.priority = Priority.HIGH
        request.networkType = NetworkType.ALL
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")

        fetch.enqueue(
            request,
            Func { updatedRequest -> Timber.d("request updated: ${updatedRequest.id})") },
            Func { error: Error? -> Timber.d("Error: ${error?.name}")}
        )

    }
}
```